modal perfect verb usage
I have a question regarding the tense chronology when 'would have' is used in the following examples:
Introduction


I phoned my wife at 7 pm. I knew she would have completed her work by
then.

Here, 'Would have completed' (modal perfect) comes in the time earlier than 'knew' (simple past)





I didn't see Jim, or I would have spoken to him.

Here, 'didn't see' (past tense) comes before the modal perfect (would have spoken) in the timeline.
Shouldn't this be written: I hadn't seen Jim, or I would have spoken to him?
(corresponding to the conditional "If I had seen Jim, I would have spoken to him") Or, Is it that conditional format need not be followed when it is not written with the if,...then,... format?
Thanks!

As a general rule, I'd use a simpler form over a fancier one, if it does the job. "I didn't see Jim, or I would have ..." is clear enough.

Please explain the timeline how it matches with the first example where simple past comes after modal perfect. Simpler and all is fine.

Timeline #1 = I didn't see Jim. If I did see him, I would have spoken to him.

That is my question. There, the timeline ( If simple past, then modal perfect)  is just the opposite of the first example where modal perfect comes before past (as it should).  Some experts in conditionals can guide us. By the way, there is No conditional as 'If I did see/saw him, I would have spoken...). It should be: If I had seen him, I would have...)

The two sentences are using 'would have' to achieve very different grammatical ends.
In the first sentence, we are dealing with reality, and we must place the moment when the wife will complete her work before the moment when the husband calls her.

He called his wife after he knew she would have finished.

"Would have" is used as the past tense of "will have". The husband is looking back into the past from a point in the more recent past.
In the second sentence we are dealing with a subjunctive/irrealis mood of something indefinite. These moods do not have 'tense' or place in time, per se. These express potential and uncertainty. It just so happens that in English 'would have' can also be used to express uncertainty or 'subjunctive' senses, when used with 'if' (or in this case a conjunction 'or' which suggests a choice between alternatives).
A simpler phrasing which makes the subjunctive construction clearer is as follows:

I did not see Jim. If I did, I would have spoken to him.

The sentence you provide instead uses 'or' and implies words that, if included, help make the subjunctive construction of the clause clearer.

I did not see Jim, or [else, if I did,] I would have spoken to him.

English's ability to exclude many implied words does not help learners in examples like this!
"Not seeing Jim" is simple past: we know it definitely happened. The rest of the sentence is about a hypothetical situation that could potentially have happened, but has no place in time, and therefore it is given a clause with a subjunctive mood.
You could also use 'had not seen', but there is nothing more grammatical about using 'had not' rather than 'did not'.
If there is any fault in the second sentence, it is in the use of 'or', which does require the reader/listener to do quite a lot of heavy lifting by implication. If I was to edit the sentence, I might suggest that at the very least 'or else' be used, or perhaps 'otherwise'. But I don't think it's technically wrong.

That makes sense fred2. I have upvoted your answer. Thanks!

This answer is additional to the excellent notes by fred2.
The OP quotes the following sentence:

I didn't see Jim, or I would have spoken to him.

And asks:

Shouldn't this be written: I hadn't seen Jim, or I would have spoken to him?

Now the hidden question here is, Which tense is right? But it's really important to understand that this is the wrong question, because right and wrong depend on context. The best question to ask is, What tense do I use to say what I need to say?
To illustrate this, consider two variations of the above sentence:

I hadn't seen Jim before I left work today, or I would have spoken to him.
I didn't see Jim when I arrived at work today, or I would have spoken to him.

In sentence #1, I chose hadn't seen as the tense because I wanted to suggest that the not seeing occurred over a period of time, the whole time that I was at work. That period in total was prior to the moment that I left. In sentence #2, the focus is on one particular time, the moment that I arrived at work. The simple past tense communicates that better.
Past tense or perfect tense? In fact, both of them are good tools in your language toolbox.

Thank You! I have upvoted your answer.
